# Differentiating $V_c=V_s(1-e^{-t/T})$

Tags: calculus

I have a formula for an electronic circuit as follows

$$V_c=V_s(1-e^{-t/T})$$
Apparently this differentiates to $$(V_s/T) e^{-t/T}$$

I say apparently because I looked up the answer which is a bit naughty but I can't figure it out. Even with the answer I'm unable to determine how to get from a to b.

Can someone explain the process here and dumb it down a bit please. I'm a middle aged man and well out of practice

Thanks for help

Comment: "naughty": what ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust I think he means the act of looking up the answer is naughty.

Comment: Please share the answer you looked up. Otherwise it seems ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt} V_s(1-e^{-t/T})
&=  V_s \frac{d}{dt} (1-e^{-t/T})
&\text{$V_s$ is a constant factor, can be pulled out of the derivative}
\\
&= V_s \frac{d}{dt}(- e^{-t/T}) & \text{$1$ is additive constant, has derivative zero}
\\
&= -V_s \frac{d}{dt} e^{-t/T} & \text{$-1$ is constant factor, can be pulled out}
\end{align}

To differentiate $e^{-t/T}$, use the chain rule. With $f(x) = e^x$ and $g(t) = -t/T$, we have $f(g(t)) = e^{-t/T}$. Using the fact that $f'(x) = e^x$ and $g'(t) = -1/T$, we have
$$\frac{d}{dt} e^{-t/T} = f'(g(t)) \cdot g'(t) = e^{-t/T} \cdot (-1/T).$$
Plugging this back in above gives you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The expression is the sum of a constant and a negative exponential. Remember that the derivative of a sum is the sum of derivatives, the derivative of a constant is zero, and the derivative of an exponential is proportional to that exponential.